# Не работает код в typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Не выводится код после компиляции в ts. Пытаюсь собрать все в одном файле с таким конфигом

```
  {
        "compilerOptions": {
            // "target": "ES6",
            "module": "AMD",
            "rootDir": "./../../editor/ts/",
            "outFile": "./../../editor/js/editor.js",
            "sourceMap": true
        }
    }
```

Подключил require.js.

Тестовый код в ts такой

```
export class Editor {
    constructor(test : string) {

    }

    getTest(): void {
        console.log('test');
    } 
}

export const editor = new Editor('test');
alert('test');
console.log('test3');
editor.getTest();
```

После компиляции в js код такой

```
define("editor", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.editor = exports.Editor = void 0;
    require("amd-loader");
    var Editor = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Editor(test) {
        }
        Editor.prototype.getTest = function () {
            console.log('test');
        };
        return Editor;
    }());
    exports.Editor = Editor;
    exports.editor = new Editor('test');
    alert('test');
    console.log('test3');
    exports.editor.getTest();
});
```

Ошибок в консоли нет, но команды консоли, alert не работают. я протестил даже код с ошибками, ничего в консоли нет, как будто браузер не заходит в define. Подскажите, что не так, может require.js не тот подключаю ? Гуглил, нашел ответ, что нужно подключить amd-loader, но после добавления его в ts файл, ничего не происходит. Как правильно подключить amd-loader ? Его уже установил через npm.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `"module": "AMD"`

Comment: @OliverPatterson Да, если установить module: CommonJS, то все работает, но при компиляции будет создаваться множество файлов (сколько файлов ts, столько и js), а мне нужно именно скомпилировать все в один файл. "module": "AMD" компилирует все в один файл как и задумано, но код не работает

Comment: Чтобы "скомпилировать" все в один файл, используйте сборщик

Comment: @Александр Похоже разобрался, подключил webpack, все заработало как нужно, спасибо